# Backbone.js highlighting broken with a lot of data on the page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-relational, javascriptmvc

I am using Backbone.js in an application. I am associating segments to urls. So a segment can contain many urls and a given url can be in any segment. There is a url pane and a segment pane. The problem is the highlighting part. So,when I click on a segment, I want to highlight the urls it has. I have limited the number of urls to be displayed on a page to 200.  If there are more than 200 url's we just show the user the first 200 and for the rest, user just uses the live search to find the url he is looking for. The problem is when there are less than 200 urls and when I click on a segment, the highlighting works. When there are more than 200 urls and when a user clicks on a segment, the highlighting doesn't work. I am using slice on a collection if there are more than 200 urls, just highlight the first 200 but that doesn't work. Here is the code snippet. Does anybody have any good suggestions on how to fix this?

In SegmentView.js for the `toggleSelection` function:

```
  toggleSelection: function() {
    var max = 200;
   //get the urls
    var urls = this.App.segmentUrlCollection.urlsForSegment(this.model);
    var pixels = this.App.segmentPixelCollection.pixelsForSegment(this.model);
    if (this.selected) {
      this.deselect();
      this.selected = false;
      this.$('.summary').removeClass('selected');
      this.App.segmentCollection.each(function(segment){
       if (segment.get('name') == "Unmapped"){
          segment.view.$('.summary').addClass('unmapped');
        }
      });
      
    //If there are more than 200 urls in url Collection just highlight the first 200.
        if (this.App.urlCollection.size  > 200) {
          //problem?
            this.App.urlCollection.slice(0,199).each(function(url) {
                if (url.view.App.isUrlUnmapped(url)) {
                    url.view.$('.summary').addClass('unmapped');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            this.App.urlCollection.each(function(url) {
                if (url.view.App.isUrlUnmapped(url)) {
                    url.view.$('.summary').addClass('unmapped');
                }
            });
        }
     //deselect the urls
       _(urls).each(function(url) {
        url.view.deselect();
      });
      _(pixels).each(function(pixel) {
        pixel.view.deselect();
      });
    } else {
      this.App.segmentCollection.each(function(segment) {
        segment.view.selected = false;
        segment.view.deselect();
      });
          this.App.segmentCollection.each(function(segment){
       if (segment.view.$('.summary').hasClass('unmapped')){
          segment.view.$('.summary').removeClass('unmapped');
        }
      });
      //If there are more than 200 urls in url Collection just highlight the first 200.
        if (this.App.urlCollection.size  > 200) {
           //problem?
            this.App.urlCollection.slice(0,199).each(function(url) {
                if (url.view.$('.summary').hasClass('unmapped')) {
                    url.view.$('.summary').removeClass('unmapped');
                }
               // url.view.deselect();
            });
        }
        else {
            this.App.urlCollection.each(function(url) {
                if (url.view.$('.summary').hasClass('unmapped')) {
                    url.view.$('.summary').removeClass('unmapped');
                }
               // url.view.deselect();
            });
        }

 //If there are more than 200 urls in url Collection just highlight the first 200.
       if (this.App.urlCollection.size  > 200) {
         //problem?
            this.App.urlCollection.slice(0,199).each(function(url) {
                 url.view.deselect();
            });
        }
        else {
            this.App.urlCollection.each(function(url) {
                 url.view.deselect();

            });
        }


      this.App.pixelCollection.each(function(pixel) {
        pixel.view.deselect();
      });

      this.select();
      this.selected = true;
      this.$('.summary').addClass('selected');
       //select the urls
      _(urls).each(function(url) {
        url.view.select();
      });
      _(pixels).each(function(pixel) {
        pixel.view.select();
      });
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably getting a JavaScript error that is preventing your code from running because `slice` is a javascript method for arrays. Backbone collections are not arrays, so this method does not exist.

you can get a copy of the array of models from the collection by calling `urlCollection.toArray()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I tried that and looked to the console in Firebug and saw the error "url.view is undefined" for  the lines "if (url.view.$('.summary').hasClass('unmapped')) { "